# Check if attribute that is not specific value

Tags: attributes, product-attribute

I want to create a php if rule, that checks if a attribute got data and is not "zaterdag 1 januari 2000".

If it is not empty or does not have the value "zaterdag 1 januari 2000", it should display some text.

I currently display the attribute with this line:

```
<?php if($_product->getData('nieuwe_voorraad')) : ?>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: this is dropdown attribute or input?

Comment: @QaisarSatti It is a input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if value is not empty and not equal too

```
<?php if($_product->getData('nieuwe_voorraad')!="" &&  $_product->getData('nieuwe_voorraad')!='zaterdag 1 januari 2000') : ?>
some text
<?php endif;?>
```